# Collecting tweets with geocode in R

Tags: r, twitter, geocode

I am attempting to map tweets that have the hastag #trump or include trump in their language. I only want to collect tweets that have a geocode tied to them. I tried

```
library(tweetR)
tweets <- searchTwitter("#trump OR Trump or trump", n = 200, lang = "en", geocode = '33.7490, 84.3880, 1000mi')
```

but was not getting any results. How can I search for tweets that include trump and have a geocode?

Comment: And searchTwitter is a function you wrote on your own or from an existing package?